# Using Django to Create Child Sites

Tags: django, architecture

I am creating a series of small sites, I'm using the django framework. The theory goes a user comes to a master site, signs up, then he gets his own child site.

Example:

navigate to example.com
user creates an account "mysite"
user then gets his own site: mysite.example.com and he can configure this all he wants
My question: * would it be better to have a "gold" version of the site that gets created for each site?

for instance: cp ~/goldsite ~/mysite and change the database pointers appropriately ** the downside is if I ever have to do maintenance on a file, I would have to change all subsites.

...or * have one host and configure the database to support multiple sites. The DB might get messy.

Any feedback would be great.

Comment: When it comes to programming, redundancy is death, so better messy than dead! And eventually everything becomes messy ... Back to the question, Django supports multiple sites and multiple databases. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#site-id). You should be fine with copying just the settings.py and and wsgi files and change them accordingly (point to the correct path for static files, media files etc ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same code/database for all the users, otherwise it would be a nightmare to maintain the code. Think about database migrations, backups, update the code with git...

> ...or * have one host and configure the database to support multiple sites. The DB might get messy.

It shouldn't be really complex, associate each website object with an user and use the permissions properly.